# MQTT payload size, packet loss, transmission time

Tags: size, packet, latency, mqtt

I have an MQTT client on an Intel Galileo board and the broker on my desktop. I'm interested in measuring

1. The payload size of a message
2. packet loss rates
3. The transmission time between the client and the broker.

Could anybody suggest the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Payload size is going to be pretty much determined by the message you send since the MQTT header is a fixed size on top of this. You can easily measure the packet size with something like Wireshark (network sniffing tool)

Since MQTT runs over TCP loss shouldn't be a problem (apart from a performance impact) as they will get re-sent. And this is likely to be a function of the quality of the network you are using, wifi/cellular is likely to loose more than wired. Again the best way to measure this will probably be with a network sniffer on both ends and comparing the traffic.

The capture from the last point will probably cover the network transmission time for this, but if you want to include the broker handling time then best bet is to publish and subscribe from the same client and time the round trip time.